# Ruby Array#sort_by on array of ActiveRecord objects seems slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, sorting, activerecord

I'm writing a controller index method that returns a sorted array of ActiveRecord `Contact` objects. I need to be able to sort the objects by attributes or by the output of an instance method. For example, I need to be able to sort by `contact.email` as well as `contact.photos_uploaded`, which is an instance method that returns the number of photos a contact has.

I can't use ActiveRecord's native `order` or `reorder` method because that only works with attributes that are columns in the database. I know from reading that normally `array#sort_by` is much faster than `array#sort` for complex objects.

My question is, how can I improve the performance of this block of code in my controller method? The code currently

```
contacts = company.contacts.order(last_name: :asc)

if params[:order].present? && params[:order_by].present? && (Contact::READ_ONLY_METHOD.include?(params[:order_by].to_sym) || Contact::ATTRIBUTES.include?(params[:order_by].to_sym))
    contacts = contacts.sort_by do |contact|
        if params[:order_by] == 'engagement'
            contact.engagement.to_i
        else
            contact.method(params[:order_by].to_sym).call
        end
    end

    contacts.reverse! if params[:order] == 'desc'
end
```

The root problem here (I think) is that I'm calling `sort_by` on `contacts`, which is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that could have several hundred contacts in it. Ultimately I paginate the results before returning them to the client, however they need to be sorted before they can be paginated. When I run the block of code above with 200 contacts, it takes an average of 900ms to execute, which could be a problem in a production environment if a user has thousands of contacts.

Here's my `Contact` model showing some relevant methods. The reason I have a special `if` clause for `engagement` is because that method returns a string that needs to be turned into an integer for sorting. I'll probably refactor that before I commit any of this to return an integer. Generally all the methods I might sort on return an integer representing the number of associated objects (e.g. number of photos, stories, etc that a contact has). There are many others, so for brevity I'm just showing a few.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :invites
    has_many :responses, through: :invites
    has_many :photos
    has_many :requests
    belongs_to :company

    ATTRIBUTES = self.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)
    READ_ONLY_METHOD = [:engagement, :stories_requested, :stories_submitted, :stories_published]

    def engagement
        invites = self.invites.present? ? self.invites.count : 1
        responses = self.responses.present? ? self.responses.count : 0
        engagement = ((responses.to_f / invites).round(2) * 100).to_i.to_s + '%'
    end

    def stories_requested
        self.invites.count
    end

    def stories_submitted
        self.responses.count
    end

    def stories_published
        self.responses.where(published: true).count
    end
end
```

When I run a query to get a bunch of contacts and then serialize it to get the values for all these methods, it only takes ~80ms for 200 contacts. The vast majority of the slowdown seems to be happening in the `sort_by` block.

The output of the controller method should look like this after I iterate over `contacts` to build a custom data structure, using this line of code:

```
@contacts = Hash[contacts.map { |contact| [contact.id, ContactSerializer.new(contact)] }]
```

I've already benchmarked that last line of code so I know that it's not a major source of slowdown. [More on that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/59572186?noredirect=1)

```
{
    contacts: {
        79: {
            id: 79,
            first_name: "Foo",
            last_name: "Bar",
            email: "t@t.co",
            engagement: "0%",
            company_id: 94,
            created_at: " 9:41AM Jan 30, 2016",
            updated_at: "10:57AM Feb 23, 2016",
            published_response_count: 0,
            groups: {
                test: true,
                test23: false,
                Test222: false,
                Last: false
            },
            stories_requested: 1,
            stories_submitted: 0,
            stories_published: 0,
            amplify_requested: 1,
            amplify_completed: 1,
            photos_uploaded: 0,
            invites: [
                {
                    id: 112,
                    email: "t@t.co",
                    status: "Requested",
                    created_at: "Jan 30, 2016, 8:48 PM",
                    date_submitted: null,
                    response: null
                }
            ],
            responses: [ ],
            promotions: [
                {
                    id: 26,
                    company_id: 94,
                    key: "e5cb3bc80b58c29df8a61231d0",
                    updated_at: "Feb 11, 2016, 2:45 PM",
                    read: null,
                    social_media_posts: [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do everything you can to do the sort in the database. Sorting in code on your host increases CPU loads across the network and your Rails host. You'll have to retrieve all records, then sort, then throw away any that aren't in the current page view, then do it all again when the user switches pages. The DBM is optimized for sorting and returning subsets, reducing the load on the other boxes. If it's difficult to figure out how to sort on the DBM, then dig into your schema and adjust it. It'll pay off in the long run.

Comment: Your "I can't use ActiveRecord's native `order` or `reorder` method because that only works with attributes that are columns in the database." comment isn't correct. ORDER BY can work any SQL expression so translate what your methods do into SQL and let the database do its job.

Comment: I just updated my question with some more information for @Julie. It does query the database in the loop, so that very well could be the source of the slowdown.

Comment: I just updated my question with the output. If I can alter this code to pull these attributes from the database rather than using instance methods, that would be great. I'm just not sure how to do that when I still need to serialize the contact objects.

Comment: "array#sort_by is much faster than array#sort for complex objects" - where did you read _that_, may I ask?

Comment: Security alert: never do `contact.method(params[:order_by].to_sym).call`. For example the user can set your `order_by` param to `delete`. you need to have a whitelist of allowed column names.

Comment: @muistooshort: sorting by arbitrary SQL isn't necessarily a good idea :) (`rand()`)

Comment: What @theTinMan is hinting at is denormalized counters/fields. Add a few fields to your `contacts` table: stories_requested, stories_submitted, etc. and make sure to update them whenever corresponding related collections change. You'll be amazed by the sort performance (assuming you'll index the fields)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I read a few articles on the subject of sorting with sort vs sort_by. I also benchmarked it myself. Sort_by is twice as fast with the code block above. Also I do have a whitelist of allowed attributes/methods for sorting for security. I hate to sound like a noob, but I don't have any experience with denormalizing fields. I found a few gems that claim to handle it. Would you recommend any of them or is it better to do it without a gem?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sure but doing your sorting outside the database is an even worse idea. And how bad of an idea `order by rand()` is depends on how but the collection is :)

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH: no worries! Rails can handle some [by itself](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (search for `counter_cache`). The rest can be relatively easily implemented in your app (it's just a few `after_save` hooks, or something)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use a `counter_cache`. I found a gem called `counter_culture` that seems to handle this process nicely. I implemented that along with a background job that runs periodically to ensure the counts are accurate. Not perfect, but far faster and more scalable than my first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if params[:order_by] == 'stories_submitted'
  contact_ids = company.contact_ids
  # count all invites that have the relevant contact ids
  invites=Invite.where(contact_id:contact_ids).group('contact_id').count
  invites_contact_ids = invites.map(&:first)
  # Add contacts with 0 invites
  contact_ids.each{|c| invites.push([c, 0]) unless invites_contact_ids.include?(c)}
  # Sort all invites by id (add .reverse to the end of this for sort DESC)
  contact_id_counts=invites.sort_by{|r| r.last}.map(&:first)      
  # The [0, 10] limits you to the lowest 10 results
  contacts=Contact.where(id: contact_id_counts[0, 10])
  contacts.sort_by!{|c| contact_id_counts.index(c.id)}
end
```

Comment: I think I see where you're going with this approach. The problem is it selects only those contacts for which `stories_submitted > 0`. I'm working on trying to adapt the block to get all the contacts...

Comment: Got it.  Something like the updated version above should get all the responses.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. I edited your code to show the output of each line up until the point where I get stuck. I can't figure out exactly how to get the block to do what it's supposed to do. Keep in mind that responses `belong_to` invites, not contacts, though a contact `has_many` responses `through` invites.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH try this code with `invites` instead of `responses` then.  You should be able to get it to work with responses with a little more logic, but it should work for invites as-is.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it t work, but I ultimately ended up just using counter caches to store the data in the database along with a scheduled job in `Resque Scheduler` to update the values periodically. I realized that it was the best option for scalability.